# Computing $\int^{\pi/2}_0{\frac{1}{4\cos{x}+5}}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by substituting $\cos{x} = (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, definite-integrals, logarithms, complex-integration

If an integral involves real trigonometric function, is substituting the definition via the complex exponential function a valid way of solving it? 
Here is my example, I get the right answer but I'm not sure whether the derivation is valid, especially the part with complex logarithm:
$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0{\frac{1}{4\cos{x} + 5}}dx$$
$$\int{\frac{1}{4\cos{x} + 5}}dx = \int{\frac{1}{4\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right) + 5}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix} + \frac{5}{2}}}dx$$
Let $u = e^{ix}$, $du = ie^{ix}$, $dx = \frac{1}{iu}du$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{iu(u+u^{-1}+\frac{5}{2})}}du = \frac{1}{2i}\int{\frac{1}{u^2 + \frac{5}{2}u + 1}}du = \frac{1}{2i}\int{\frac{1}{(u+\frac{1}{2})(u+2)}}du$$
After PFD I get $$\frac{1}{3i}\int{\frac{1}{u+\frac{1}{2}}}du - \frac{1}{3i}\int{\frac{1}{u+2}}du = \frac{1}{3i}\left(\ln{(u+\frac{1}{2})} - \ln{(u+2)}\right) = \frac{1}{3i}ln{\left(\frac{e^{ix} + \frac{1}{2}}{e^{ix} + 2}\right)} =: F(x)$$
$$F(\frac{\pi}{2}) - F(0) = \frac{1}{3i}\left(\ln{\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}}{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} + 2}} - \ln{\frac{e^0 + \frac{1}{2}}{e^0 + 2}}\right) = \frac{1}{3i}\left(\ln{\frac{\frac{1}{2} + i}{2 + i}} - \ln{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{3i}\left(\ln{( \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{10}i)} - \ln{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{3i}\ln{\left( \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{5}i\right)} = \frac{1}{3i}\left( \ln{\sqrt{(\frac{4}{5})^2 + (\frac{3}{5})^2 }} + i\arctan{\frac{(\frac{3}{5})}{(\frac{4}{5})}}\right) = \frac{1}{3i}\left(\ln{(1) + i\arctan{(\frac{3}{4})}}\right) = \frac{1}{3}\arctan{(\frac{3}{4})}$$

Comment: You can check your $F(x)$ by differentiating to see that you got it right.  If you can do that, then you do not need to worry about whether your methods for getting there are OK or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster way is to exploit real methods.

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}\stackrel{x=2z}{=}2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dz}{1+8\cos^2 z}\stackrel{z=\arctan u}{=}2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{9+u^2}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{3}\arctan\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the Kepler angle substitution:
$$\begin{align}\sin\psi&=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin x}{1+e\cos x}\\
\cos\psi&=\frac{\cos x+e}{1+e\cos x}\\
d\psi&=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}dx}{1+e\cos x}\end{align}$$
For $0<e<1$. So
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}&=\frac15\frac1{\sqrt{1-e^2}}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}e}d\psi=\frac{\cos^{-1}e}{5\sqrt{1-e^2}}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac45\right)}{3}=\frac13\tan^{-1}\left(\frac34\right)=\frac23\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)\end{align}$$
With $e=\frac45$.